# Translation not working when using siunitx + glossaries + polyglossia + xindy + LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, glossaries, siunitx, polyglossia

I'm trying to move to a modern LaTeX setup, by using LuaLaTex, polyglossia, glossaries + xindy.

When I create a German document with a glossary, the title of the glossary correctly changes to "Glossar", the German translation of glossary.

If I add `\usepackage{siunitx}` to load siunitx, translation will break - the title of the glossary will change back to "Glossary".
Example (compile with lualatex + makeglossaries + lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}{name = ä, description = A Umlaut}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
Testing the entry: \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

Removing the line to load `siunitx` will fix this problem, as will loading `translator` explicity (before loading `siunitx`) with `\usepackage[german]{translator}`.

I believe this happens because `siunitx.sty` loads `translator` without any language options with `\RequirePackage { translator }`.

I'm not an expert, so I'm not sure if this behaviour is to be expected. But from a user's perspective, it seems siunitx breaks translation. Is this a bug? If so, in which package, and who should I report this to?

---

One other thing: xindy will report `Cannot locate xindy module for language german in codepage utf8`, and will switch to language `general`, unless I add `\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried loading the `siunitx` package with the option `locale=DE`?

Comment: In my actual document, I use the `locale=DE` option - I just removed it for the minimal example. It doesn't affect this translation issue, it only changes things like commas as decimal separators.

Comment: I had the same problem but hadn't noticed it was `siunitx`'s fault, nice catch! I'm using XeLaTeX, not LuaLaTeX, but the problem seems to be fixed if `siunitx` is loaded **after** `glossaries`, without needing to explicitly load `translator`. Can you confirm?

Comment: You're right, it's fixed if I load `siunitx` after `glossaries`. But I hate all these load order dependencies, especially since `hyperref`'s manual states `Make sure it comes last of your loaded packages`, and the `glossaries` manual states `you should load the hyperref package
before the glossaries package`. From a user's perspective, it shouldn't matter when I load `siunitx`... I believe this problem occurs because `siunitx` doesn't use `polyglossia` correctly, or uses `translator` incorrectly. I'll try to get `siunitx`'s author to notice this post.

Answer (score 6):

The `glossaries` package will use `translator` if loaded for translating strings. The `translator` package requires that the language name is given as a global (class) option (which is usual `babel` 'best practice'). Unfortunately, `polyglossia` doesn't use this method as standard, but it will work happily. Try

```
\documentclass[german]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usedictionary{german}
\newglossaryentry{a}{name = ä, description = A Umlaut}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
Testing the entry: \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

Note that this is really not the fault of `siunitx` beyond the fact it loads `translator` if available: you'd see the same with any package loading `translator` or indeed if like in my demo you load it directly.

Comment: You're right, it does happen with other packages that load translator. I just didn't/don't understand the interaction between `polyglossia`, `translator`, and other packages like `siunix` enough to assess whether this behaviour is to be expected or not. Loading `translator` explicitly and setting the language works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly load the `glossaries-polyglossia` package to fix the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-polyglossia}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}{name = ä, description = A Umlaut}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
Testing the entry: \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of glossary]

In some cases, you may also need to use the `translate=false` package option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[xindy,translate=false]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-polyglossia}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{a}{name = ä, description = A Umlaut}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
Testing the entry: \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

Although this particular example seems to work without it.

Comment: This works, but I think it only fixes the issue for the glossaries package. A translation issue will still occur when another packages that translates strings with `translator` is loaded, because `translator` doesn't seem to recognize the language set by polyglossia. (Thanks for the excellent glossaries package!)